# I Heard the world gets holier on holy days how does this work with Binyan HaMalchut

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, yom-kippur, chasidut-hasidism, rosh-hashanah-new-year, rosh-chodesh-new-month

BH

I heard in a class on Kuntrus Umayan discourse 18 from a teacher that the whole world gets holier on holy days and that for example on Yomkipur Malchut of Azilut rises to Dikna of Arich Anpin while on Shabbat Malchut of Azilut only reaches to Abba in the discourse the Rebbe Rashab says though that we have to build Malchut which I Assume is Malchut of Atzilut from Rosh Hashana to YomKippur and that Hashem some how takes out his inter presence out and let’s us coronates him at that time. So my questions are does the world get holier on holy days and we have a higher revelation of Malchut on those days? And if yes how? And also if yes how do you reconcile this with the building of Malchut from Rosh Hashanna to YomKippur where we have to be the ones who build it to the level of Dikna of Arich Anpin because isn’t it rising already due to the holiness of the day?

Comment: The questions answer each other. To the extent that a person is *mevatel* himself to *malchus shamayim*, the *malchus shamayim* is instantiated within the person himself, and therefore the *aliyah* of *malchus shamayim* generally and the *aliyah* of the person become synonymous.